# Retornar Json e Colocar em Array Multidimensional

Tags: javascript, json

Estou fazendo uma requisição para montar um gráfico usando o Flot Js.

Estou retornando um Json assim:

```
[{
    "status": "Finalizado",
    "id_status": "4",
    "total_chamado": "2",
    "mes": "4",
    "ano": "2015"
}, {
    "status": "Finalizado",
    "id_status": "4",
    "total_chamado": "1",
    "mes": "5",
    "ano": "2015"
}, {
    "status": "Finalizado",
    "id_status": "4",
    "total_chamado": "1",
    "mes": "6",
    "ano": "2015"
}, {
    "status": "Finalizado",
    "id_status": "4",
    "total_chamado": "1",
    "mes": "7",
    "ano": "2015"
}, {
    "status": "Em Aberto",
    "id_status": "1",
    "total_chamado": "1",
    "mes": "8",
    "ano": "2015"
}, {
    "status": "Finalizado",
    "id_status": "4",
    "total_chamado": "1",
    "mes": "8",
    "ano": "2015"
}, {
    "status": "Em Aberto",
    "id_status": "1",
    "total_chamado": "3",
    "mes": "9",
    "ano": "2015"
}, {
    "status": "Em Aberto",
    "id_status": "1",
    "total_chamado": "1",
    "mes": "10",
    "ano": "2015"
}, {
    "status": "Em Aberto",
    "id_status": "1",
    "total_chamado": "1",
    "mes": "11",
    "ano": "2015"
}]
```

E eu preciso que no **JavaScript** ele fique dessa forma:

`vetor = [ [mes, total], [mes, total], [mes, total], [mes, total], [mes, total], [mes, total] ];`

Estou tentando assim, mas não está dando certo. O gráfico não monta.

```
var caixa_entrada = []
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   cache: false,
   url: baseURL + '/dashboard/grafico-chamado',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function(index, value){
         caixa_entrada.push([index, value.total_chamado]);
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui (tirando a parte do ajax) e o loop parece funcionar, montando um array multidimensional. Será que não tem problema em alguma outra parte do código?

Comment: Ah meu... eu sei o que é! Mas não lembro como resolver. A variável está dentro de um `callback`. Como que tiro ela pra fora ?

Comment: é, pode ser problema de escopo mesmo.

Comment: Resolvido. Coloquei `async: false` nas options.

Comment: Ainda bem que resolveu. Vou apagar meus comentários aqui jajá.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fim, o problema que estava acontecendo comigo não tinha relação com a montagem do `array` multidimensional para a montagem do gráfico.

O problema estava na variável `caixa_entrada`, que era o `callback` da função. Essa variável é usada na função que monta os dados e valores para o gráfico, mas estava ficando com valor `undefined`.

Daí, comecei a pensar no que poderia ser e logo percebi que essa variável era um `callback` e queria usar fora do escopo. Assim não dá pra manter você, pequeno Padawan!

Para solucionar fiz assim:

```
var caixa_entrada = []
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   cache: false,
   url: baseURL + '/dashboard/grafico-chamado',
   dataType: 'json',
   async: false,
   success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function(index, value){
         caixa_entrada.push([index, value.total_chamado]);
      });
   }
});
```

Adicionei o parâmetro `async: false` para fazer uma requisição **síncrona** e não **assíncrona**, no qual essa função é executada **depois** da função que monta o gráfico.

Quando ela é **síncrona** é executada **antes** da função que monta o gráfico e assim consigo usar a variável.

Eu não gosto de teorias, gosto de exemplos de código. Então devo ter explicado bem mais ou menos, mais pra menos, o que significa o `async:false`. E claro que nem deve ser apenas isso a sua função.

Então se alguém explicar melhor, ficaria legal, embora já tenha visto algumas perguntas relacionadas aqui no SOpt.